# PHP SQL insert not working but I copied the structure from code that works on different table

Tags: insert

I have tried forever and searched everywhere I can think of, but I cannot see why this sql insert command doesn't work. Please help me see the light.

```
<?php $conn = mysqli_connect("pdb3.freehostingeu.com", "2199634_class",  "don21121", "2199634_class");

if (!$conn) {

die("connection Failed:". mysqli_connect_error());

}
 echo "";

?>

    <form action="examples.php">
 <?php
   $sql = "INSERT INTO test (a, b, c, d )
                    VALUES ('aaa','bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd')";

 ?>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: How can you reasonably expect us to say something interesting without seeing your code???

Comment: .  <?php        $sql = "INSERT INTO test (a, b, c, d )    VALUES ('aaa','bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd')";             ?>

Comment: Code goes into the question, **not** in comments!!! And the code should be complete, ie, stand on its own, ie, show how you connect to the database, how you execute the query, etc. Read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)